# Magento: Build Reviews Collection From an Array of Product IDs

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm attempting to build a product reviews collection that combines reviews from multiple different products. I'm using the following code, but the collection only returns the reviews from the first product ID listed in the array, instead of both product IDs.

```
$entity_ids = "153435, 153438";

$reviewcollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()->addEntityFilter('product', array('in' => $entity_ids));
$reviewcollection->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)->setDateOrder()->addRateVotes();

$_items = $reviewcollection->getItems();`
```

Any ideas how to get the collection to combine the reviews from multiple product IDs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$entity_ids = array(153435, 153438);

$reviewcollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', Mage_Review_Model_Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT)
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_pk_value', array('in' => $entity_ids))
    ->setDateOrder()
    ->addRateVotes()
;

$_items = $reviewcollection->getItems();
```

Comment: Thanks Drew! The slightly modified version of your code did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

addEntityFilter() doesn't accept an array.  You could try addFieldToFilter($field, $condition) or override the collection and write your own method.  Alternatively, you could just loop through your ids and merge the results.